# Different results running script from command line vs. PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell-exec

I have a bash script that tests pconn idle timeout.  If I run it from the command line, it works fine.  If I run the exact same script from PHP using shell_exec, I get different results.

**EDIT:  The results I'm interested in are the HTTP 200 response, that is expected, vs the HTTP 400 response when the script is run from PHP.**

I've verified that the arguments are making it into the script because if I echo the variables from the script itself I can see the proper data.

However, just to be certain it's not some kind of encoding/escaping issue, I've even hard-coded the values in the script and simply run the script via PHP and I still am not getting the proper response back.

Since simplifying the script I think I've removed anything PHP related (passing variables to the script).  So what could possibly cause this issue?

The script:

```
vbetoglo@prod-lamp-web03:~$ cat pconns.sh 
echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.betoglou.com\nConnection: keep-Alive\n\n" | time /test/openssl/bin/openssl s_client --connect origin.betoglou.com:443 --servername www.betoglou.com -ign_eof
```

The PHP Code, you can ignore the inputs since the script itself is hard coded right now:

```
function pconns($hostname, $path, $origin){
        $cmd="/scripts/webtools/pconns.sh";
        $results=shell_exec($cmd);
        ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
        Results for <?=$origin;?>:<br><br>
        <xmp style="white-space: pre-wrap; font-size: 14px"><?
                echo $results;
        ?></xmp>
        </div>
        <?
}
```

I've also tried moving the call for the  script into the shell_exec line (I know it doesn't matter).
So here are the results when run command line:

```
vbetoglo@prod-lamp-web03:~$ /scripts/webtools/pconns.sh 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = betoglou.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = betoglou.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = betoglou.com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3248 bytes and written 444 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: D7A2EE46C46091AB53D20174C9C0B589DC784EAA11E24798163967D4ACD7EA02
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: CC99647A30CD8E23B270A6C70B1E258C1F649639044B3C4AC73D355E2502DAF8F1B73104565C240ED1674360D935E075
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 6e 77 17 4b 4c 4e 18 d0-1c 9f 5d 20 d9 dc d6 38   nw.KLN....] ...8
    0010 - 3b fd e3 bc bf ba 2e a9-9f c2 3e c2 53 bd 10 12   ;.........>.S...
    0020 - 22 e0 f5 31 5b ff 93 25-0c cd 96 a9 9f 3e a3 d4   "..1[..%.....>..
    0030 - 65 41 da ee 13 45 8c 49-08 79 8e 83 59 be f6 2d   eA...E.I.y..Y..-
    0040 - c7 2b ec fc f2 79 04 d8-d6 59 53 f1 eb 71 3c 91   .+...y...YS..q<.
    0050 - c7 e8 f7 b8 8a c4 25 7e-35 af fa 6c 1b 48 77 90   ......%~5..l.Hw.
    0060 - 17 d0 3a 92 2a 03 ad 87-76 9a 77 1c cf 56 3b 30   ..:.*...v.w..V;0
    0070 - f4 14 6b 77 94 96 27 33-66 b7 f8 cd 35 3f b0 3b   ..kw..'3f...5?.;
    0080 - 07 20 f2 76 66 4e 08 a2-8e fa 3d f9 6b 33 78 1d   . .vfN....=.k3x.
    0090 - 20 2b 36 b1 08 1f a8 ab-1b 17 99 08 83 86 85 b3    +6.............
    00a0 - 56 79 b1 7b cf be db 09-23 e2 8e ed 5d 8c 8b 43   Vy.{....#...]..C
    00b0 - c0 e7 c4 5e 53 89 12 7b-61 05 1c 13 63 7c 3b 86   ...^S..{a...c|;.
    00c0 - 88 5e c4 f4 28 9f e2 e7-7d 75 a2 a7 c5 25 f2 2b   .^..(...}u...%.+

    Start Time: 1563400639
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 21:57:19 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 22728
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

{{{source code removed}}}
closed
0.00user 0.00system 0:02.12elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15868maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1267minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

BUT, if I run it PHP:

```
Results for asd:

depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = betoglou.com
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = betoglou.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = betoglou.com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3248 bytes and written 444 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: B4359A2A9E37D2B08990B2B633FCA34FBE69FDAFE2219F9F809AA251BFE46372
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: BA7685698B51974B02EB85BB21A684AA1CF1997496841EA23505F43697611AE4709D83FB82C6091DE1155B58CAA76649
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 6e 77 17 4b 4c 4e 18 d0-1c 9f 5d 20 d9 dc d6 38   nw.KLN....] ...8
    0010 - b8 df b2 ee 72 f3 f5 eb-0f 10 83 7f 2d 7b 61 1e   ....r.......-{a.
    0020 - 7e 54 89 7f f3 20 60 23-f6 01 4c 54 94 56 e0 58   ~T... `#..LT.V.X
    0030 - 39 28 b8 c7 46 4d 40 14-00 b1 1f c0 b0 88 e1 d4   9(..FM@.........
    0040 - 02 d9 0a 1e d8 f0 96 72-af 15 1a b9 e7 0e 93 1a   .......r........
    0050 - 53 ec 3b 0d e3 e3 43 91-70 95 3f 3d 68 b2 3d 14   S.;...C.p.?=h.=.
    0060 - 85 72 7c db 99 fb 6d 15-7e 40 12 72 bb db aa 41   .r|...m.~@.r...A
    0070 - 78 65 56 09 05 29 f7 09-6a 69 9f 90 2d a8 84 b8   xeV..)..ji..-...
    0080 - a4 99 3f 4a 55 34 df bf-dd f4 c8 8c bd 1c 35 6c   ..?JU4........5l
    0090 - cc 01 6a 9c 38 a1 ef bd-01 a5 41 31 58 d3 19 20   ..j.8.....A1X.. 
    00a0 - b5 75 ff 3e 1c 0d 3b c9-97 36 a5 b4 77 aa 69 95   .u.>..;..6..w.i.
    00b0 - 25 a6 96 a5 b9 cb 8f 9e-05 cd b7 df 0f d4 b1 b4   %...............
    00c0 - f8 77 5d 98 d9 3b 2d 5e-0d 58 66 cc 4e 35 99 4f   .w]..;-^.Xf.N5.O

    Start Time: 1563400624
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: no
---
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 21:57:04 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
closed
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.15elapsed 7%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15624maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1266minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Comment: The differences are  `Results for asd:` and the location of `CONNECTED(00000003)`?

Comment: `Results for asd:` is in the PHP code, so you won't see that when you run the script by hand.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I can see the differences - the question is why.  Running the same script via command line vs. php shell_exec should give me the exact same results (everything is hard-coded for troubleshooting).  Both php and cli are on the same machine.

Comment: I'm trying to understand which differences you're talking about.

Comment: The differences I am interested in is the 200 results vs the 400 result, not the formatting.  Sorry if I wasn't specific.

Comment: I expect an HTTP 200 response, but I get a 400 when the script is run via PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script doesn't begin with a shebang line, it's being executed using whatever shell is being used by the caller. That's `/bin/sh` for PHP, but probably `/bin/bash` for you.

This is probably changing whether the `echo` command supports the `-en` option to process escape sequences -- it works interactively, but not from PHP.

You should always begin scripts with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` to make sure they use the shell you want.

And rather than `echo`, use `printf`, which has more consistent behavior.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.betoglou.com\nConnection: keep-Alive\n\n" | time /test/openssl/bin/openssl s_client --connect origin.betoglou.com:443 --servername www.betoglou.com -ign_eof
```

Comment: AH wow, thank you for catching my brain fart.  I'll give printf a try as well.

Comment: Note that with `printf`, if there are any variable parts of the string, they should be passed as separate arguments and interpolated with `%s` in the control string. For example, if the hostname was a variable, you'd use something like `printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: %s\nConnection: keep-Alive\n\n" "$host" | ...`